# Where should I do my research, and are low research effort questions bad?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

From the help center [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Search, and research
>
> ...and keep track of what you find. Even if you
>   don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to
>   related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding
>   how your question is different from the rest.

This seems to imply research is searching for duplicates on SO. While the downvote title leaves room for interpretation:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful

Which leads to a common interpretation of "research" as searching *outside* of SO.

[An answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6275781) to a related question suggests that if your research solves the problem, **even though it was not asked on SO before**, you should not ask.

## Questions

- Where should my research be done?

If research is only searching SO:

- Are low research effort questions really just duplicates?

If research includes searching *outside* of SO:

- Is a question that can be answered by searching the internet, documentation or anywhere outside of SO a bad question?
- If I ask a question that shows little or no research effort but as an immediate self answer, is it still a bad question?

Comment: A related recent discussion: [*Google one liner questions with no SO answer*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366247/2751851)

Comment: Also relevant: [*Does Stack Overflow need useless questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339216/2751851)

Comment: "Are low research effort questions really just duplicates?" - Often yes.  But not necessarily.  For example, if you ask a Java question due to misspelling a standard class name, it is poorly researched 'cos you could have looked it up.  But the chances are there won't be a Question about your particular misspelling.

Comment: "If I ask a low research effort question but as an immediate self answer, is it still a bad question?"  - IMO, mostly yes.  The question didn't need to be asked.  You could argue that it *could* make it easier for someone to do their research.  But the context is that the answer was *already* available to someone doing adequate research, so the benefit is marginal.  And if your Answer is poor quality too, then you may have done the reader a disservice by pushing a better answer down the search results!

Comment: Also relevant: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: @StephenC I didn't mean a question that took little effort, but a question that shows no research effort. Maybe the question was researched 8 hours a day for a year to reach the answer, but no research effort was shown. I have clarified the question.

Comment: Interestingly it is only the SO answering community that care about the research effort in a question. The SO consuming community just wants to see every question answered here, whether or not it can be answered in documentation somewhere else. This difference in expectations is responsible for a lot of the so-called "unfriendlyness" that users experience.

Comment: wrt immediate self-answers to low effort questions, see [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251874/839601)

Comment: @MikeWise If SO consumers don't care, it's because they don't know better. Having SO cluttered with duplicates and trivial low-effort questions ends up scattering good answers, making them more difficult to find and keep up to date (with version changes etc.). At the opposite end of the spectrum, that's the reason people go through the trouble of making canonical questions, to create one authoritative source with the one best and well-explained answer, or multiple good answers with different approaches, all viewable in one place.

Comment: Also relevant: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett - However my point stands. SO has become the goto place to find easy answers. We can try and educate the entire world to view SO in the limited way we want it to be (apparently the reference of last resort), or we can go with the flow and accept that fact that people will come to us first and try and accommodate that. I think the latter strategy has more likelihood of success.

Comment: @MikeWise: I disagree. The latter strategy is doomed to fail. There are fewer people answering questions than asking them. The only way this is sustainable is to a) keep the number of questions low enough that the smaller number of experts can keep up with them, and b) keep the questions high-quality and interesting enough that the small number of experts bother answering them.

Comment: In my personal case, it's a simple matter of math and economics: an hour spent solving other people's problems on [main] earns me nothing, an hour spent solving other people's problems at work earns me X$. So, the people whose problems I solve on [main] should ideally pay me back some other way, and the way to do that, is by asking well-formed, well-researched, interesting questions that are a joy to answer and increase my own knowledge as much as theirs. If they cannot be bothered to invest even that tiny amount of effort, then I can't be bothered, too.

Comment: @MikeWise Your point stands on its own, sure, and so does mine. The question is, though, are no-research questions bad for SO? Pretty good case that they are. What should SO do about it? (No, "educating the rest of the world" isn't on the table.) IMO, smother those questions (downvote/close). Why? To try to focus limited answerer's time on a smaller number of higher-quality questions that end up covering the same scope more efficiently.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - you are right, both are plausible viewpoints. I would have a lot more to say on this topic, but comments are famously not for dicussions.

Answer (score 31):

From [http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html):

> ### Before You Ask
>
> Before asking a technical question [on Stack Overflow], do the following:
>
> 1. Try to find an answer by searching [Stack Overflow.  Tip: Google works better than Stack Overflow search].
> 2. Try to find an answer by searching the Web.
> 3. Try to find an answer by reading the manual.
> 4. Try to find an answer by reading a FAQ.
> 5. Try to find an answer by inspection or experimentation.
> 6. Try to find an answer by asking a skilled friend.
> 7. If you're a programmer, try to find an answer by reading the source code.
>
> When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done these
> things first; this will help establish that you're not being a lazy
> sponge and wasting people's time. Better yet, display what you have
> learned from doing these things. We like answering questions for
> people who have demonstrated they can learn from the answers.

To be clear, you don't necessarily have to do *all* of these things before asking a question.  This list is meant to be comprehensive.  But you should certainly search, read the docs and share what you've tried.  On Stack Overflow, making an attempt to solve the problem yourself also usually means you've already written some code.

Comment: Nice list. I follow similar procedure, and so far asked exactly zero questions on SO.

Comment: Is there anything in the works to improve SE search? Seems like that could possibly resolve some of the issues with duplicate and poorly researched questions from newer users.

Comment: @apaul, creating teams means they will have to improve search, because the teams data won't be visible to crawlers. Can't recall where I read that... (That said, you'd have thought that SO enterprise would have had the same problem, so who knows?)

Comment: There is an irony to this answer. If *everyone* followed this advice, very few questions would ever be asked (not necessarily a bad thing). But, in addition, if this advice was applied by users over the years, SO would not have gained a lot of valuable material.

Comment: @apaul Custom Google search is an option, but... I think they have reason not to improve search. (IIRC?)

Comment: I'm with @jpp on this level of rigour being sufficient to prevent most questions from ever being asked, but I'll go a step further and make the value judgement too: that *would* be a bad thing. Doing all this is likely to be at least half an hour's work; potentially several hours, depending upon how easy to search, read, and understand the manual, FAQs and source code are. It's one thing to be critical of people posting questions where they could just Google the title and find the answer spelt out clearly in the first search result, but *this* standard is too strict.

Comment: @MarkAmery A good question *does* take half an hour of research effort, yes.

Comment: @MarkAmery I don't see the problem with saying people should be trying for just 1 hour to solve their own problem before asking us. I try way longer than that before risking wasting the communities time. Moreover; we would have less questions for sure, but a lot more *good* questions that help answer the 100 questions that *didn't* get asked.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think that's universally true. If I can frame a question in precisely the terms that people will use for Google it, and it's something thousands of people are going to look for an answer to, and it's possible to answer it in a way that's completely satisfying and will only take a couple of minutes to read, and it currently takes 29 minutes for a typical programmer to hunt down the solution themselves, then... the world still becomes a better place if I ask that question, by saving lots of man-hours from lots of people who'd otherwise all do those same 29 minutes of work.

Comment: @Mark there is no such thing as 'typical programmer'. What some people can find in 1 minute could require someone else to spend half an hour. The problem of SO is that it wants to be useful for everyone.

Comment: @artem Yes, the "typical programmer" may well be an entity who doesn't exist in reality. But all the more reason not to have such research requirements. I've asked questions, now highly-viewed and highly-upvoted, that somebody was able to answer in <10 minutes with a quote from the official docs - e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/38569401/1709587. Was my research sloppy? Maybe. So be it; such questions still help people.

Comment: Isn't this the core of SO? You don't need to dig into docs, spend hours to find a simple thing? Isn't this how SO promotes Teams for example?

Comment: @user2285236: Of course.  But that's what a Google search is for.  It's on SO because it didn't turn up in a prior Google search.

Comment: So a question is bad if it is answered with a google search?

Comment: @ClintL That's a nice straw man you erected there.

Comment: Just seems that what you said is, a question is on SO because it did not appear on a google search. So is a question bad if it is answered with a google search? It's part of the main question as well, no straw man here.

Comment: @Clint: Well, part of my point is that, if it's already been answered on Stack Overflow, it's very likely to turn up in a Google search and you will have saved a significant amount of time for yourself and those who would have to process your duplicate question.

Comment: I agree with that. However my other questions are specifically looking at non-duplicates that are answerable from resources other than SO. For the record, I am not and was not trying to argue with you or persuade you one way or another. I'm simply looking for some clarification on these questions from more experienced users than myself.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Crafting a good answer takes several hours. Some of my answers took several days to write, and an additional several hours over the years to keep up-to-date. Why *wouldn't* we expect askers to spend the same amount of time, especially considering that for every question asked there are typically multiple answers given, so that the effort of the asker is only a fraction of the total effort spent?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Because the objective is to co-operatively create Q&A pairs of use to future readers, not to achieve some cosmic balance in the effort expended by askers and answerers. If the behaviours that optimise for that objective involve less time investment by askers than answerers, then so be it. The time a waiter takes to bring me out my meal is much less than the time the chef takes to prepare it, but we don't label that an injustice and demand that the waiter walks the meal out very slowly to fix it.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, by the time you get past 7 in technologies like the .NET framework (which has open sourced its code), you will likely have a Microsoft bug report, not a question (or at best something that will likely rot on the site with no answers or get roomba'd). Also, while I like doing this research, I've never worked with anyone who even knew the reference source existed, I always point it out and they're like "wow this is awesome I never knew this existed!". I feel like if you can go all the way up to 7, there's really not much use for posting SO questions.

Answer (score 11):

[Robert's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367304/1711796) covers *where* (and *how*) to search pretty well. As for the other questions:

> Are low research effort questions really just duplicates?

A question is only a duplicate if there exists a post for it to be a duplicate of.

How much research effort put into a question doesn't change whether or not it's a duplicate, but (1) it's more likely to be a duplicate if you didn't search for an answer beforehand and (2) you may get downvoted for not showing research effort, regardless of whether the question is a duplicate.

> Is a question that can be answered by searching the internet, documentation or anywhere outside of SO a bad question?

The fact that there exists an easy-to-find answer elsewhere doesn't, by itself, make a question officially inappropriate, but any given user may respond negatively (i.e. downvote) to such a question.

Questions that can be answered from the documentation can make for good questions if the information is hard, or at least non-trivial, to find or deduce. If you're just asking something trivial like what some method returns, that's probably a bad question.

> If I ask a low research effort question but as an immediate self answer, is it still a bad question?

Questions should look roughly the same regardless of whether or not you're posting an answer yourself. A question's usefulness is not affected by whether an answer was provided by you or by someone else.

Some users may be more lenient regarding requiring visible research effort if you provide a self-answer (since finding an answer is a form of research), others may not.

Comment: The problem with moving all research-effort into the self-answer is that now we have a low-research question on the site that other users *will* use as justification for *their* low-research question. I've seen people cite heavily downvoted, closed questions with comments on them explaining why they are off-topic as evidence that their question should be allowed, too, because that one was.

Answer (score 2):

> Is a question that can be answered by searching the internet,
>   documentation or anywhere outside of SO a bad question?

It depends on what you have found. Basically, the quality of the question is determined by the quality of the answer.

If you found a blog post that completely answers you question and covers everything in great detail, spanning 3 pages, do not post the question. The answer is good, but the format is not a good fit for Stack Overflow where people prefer to have a concise explanation illustrated by one code example. The question will probably be closed as too broad.

If you found a line in documentation that completely answers the question, again, it depends. If it was easy to find and if it is easy to understand, do not post the question, it's likely to be downvoted as 'showing no research effort'.

But if you found the documentation that, while answering the question, is not completely clear, or can be interpreted in different ways which can cause confusion, this could be a great question.

Comment: To be fair, either "do not post the question", or [post it and answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (If you found a line in documentation that completely answers the question.)

Comment: easy self-answered question will attract downvotes as 'showing no research effort' (easy == no effort)

Answer (score 2):

An anecdote:

I [had an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975653/odatacontroller-returning-http-406-not-acceptable) where a .NET OData Controller I was working on was returning a `406 Not Acceptable` error. I wrote out my initial draft of the question, explaining what I had done so far. Then, before actually posting it, over the course of an hour or two I read and re-read my question, refined it, clarified and added details, until... *voila!*... I found the answer on my own!

I posted it as a self-answered question because, ultimately, I found no other question that was identical to mine. I had to piece together several other answers and some documentation to slowly figure out what I had done wrong and how to fix it.

That's the best outcome when doing your pre-ask research... you find the answer on your own. It produces way more endorphins (yummy!), plus **you remember the answer better** over the long run. Next time I run into a similar issue, I'll have a better chance of remembering how I fixed it the first time.

Of course, that's not always possible. Sometimes you just plain lack the knowledge you need and the documentation isn't clear enough on multiple readings to give you a solid answer. This scenario tends to be the exception, but it happens with greater frequency the closer you are to the cutting edge. Regardless, spend some time on your question. Keep working on it, adding details and links to documentation and other answers and you may just find that you don't need to ask a question at all in the end. Or maybe you can answer it yourself and produce something of value that betters the world. And even if you can't, you'll have produced an awesome question stuffed with links to documentation and inspiration for how to work the problem that will be valuable all on its own, even if it's never answered.