# Does asking a question on SO, itself, count as research

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

**TLDR** I *strongly believe* that the answer is no, but I want a question that addresses this simple question.

I hope I know the answer to this, but on a recent question, a commenter opined (in my response to pointing out that "lack of research" is a poster-child for downvoting):

> Research is exactly what he is doing by posting the question here. Most of us here have experience and know how to search...

Now, I believe they're clearly wrong here. I did point them to the `how-to-ask` page which unfortunately emphasises searching *within* the SO site. But many of us had concluded that the OP hadn't consulted the *product documentation* before asking their question.

So, is asking a question on SO *research* in and of itself?

Comment: Research is what you do *before* posting a question here.

Comment: You might want to reword your title a little bit to save yourself a lot of downvotes :D

Comment: @EJoshuaS -and that's *exactly* the stance I took. Another commentedrdisagreed. So I thought I would ask a clear question with a provocative title that should be answered "of course not". But the negative votes are piling in fairly fast.

Comment: Yet another prime example of why you should never respond to "Why the downvote?" other than by raising a no longer needed flag. No matter how you respond, you will be "wrong" because your opinion differs from theirs.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed - but that is, in simple terms, the question that *should* have a simple answer available on meta, and easily searchable.

Comment: Related: [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367302/4934172](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367302/4934172).

Comment: Related: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: To clarify, the OP posted a valid question, where he had tried to make it work and provided a minimum, complete and verifiable example. However, he couldn't get it to work. He also stated he was new to the language and was in the process of learning.

Comment: I would say [the checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/4934172) is also related. And usually, users are pointed to it.

Comment: Research doesn't matter if the information cannot be found on stack overflow realistically. We can't close a question as a duplicate of the product documentation. If the information already exists on stack overflow, close it as a duplicate and move on. Stack overflow exists largely due to poor examples in product documentation... and because a lot of the time people don't know the right words to use when searching, even if they have an idea in their head of what they are looking for. If you know the words to search for it seems obvious, but if you don't then you get stuff that doesn't help.

Comment: @JuanR:  I see things as "new to the language" and "in the process of learning" as noise, honestly.  Not germane to the matter at hand.

Comment: @JuanR Which is great.  But does not make his question immune to curation, especially if basic research of the documentation answers it.

Comment: [How much research? A lot. An absurd amount.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1233251)

Comment: _"To clarify, the OP posted a valid question, where he had tried to make it work and provided a minimum, complete and verifiable example. However, he couldn't get it to work. He also stated he was new to the language and was in the process of learning"_ that _sounds_ like a reasonable on-topic question to me.

Comment: @Makoto I agree to a certain degree. But I wouldn't call these 100% noise because when you're new to something, you might not be familiar with the terms and therefore your ability to do research is not at its best. That could signal others to provide you with the term that you're looking for.

Comment: @Makoto: To me personally, these things are relevant because they have an impact on your ability to search for answers. I wish my entire original comment had been posted in this question, not just a piece out of context. The OP was trying to figure it out, he [apparently] did his homework and couldn't get it to work. He came to this site for help. All I am saying is, why not just help him and move on?

Comment: That's not an excuse to lack evidence of what research has been done  @AhmedAbdelhameed.  Not knowing what to research is hard; I'll grant you that.  Not showing evidence of what you *did* research isn't what we want.

Comment: @JuanR:  Have you answered the question then?  We're really not talking about the *question* per se, we're talking about a comment related to the question.

Comment: @TinyGiant No one besides you has ever questioned the topicality of the post, and this meta question isn't about the question lacking a complete code example.  It's a question about doing research.  Stating that the question is on topic (something that you can't possibly know given the information provided, not that it matters) is irrelevant.

Comment: @Makoto: If you are referring to the original question, I was in the process of doing it and someone else posted the answer so I backed off.

Comment: @Makoto: By the way, I was the one who posted the original comment that sparked this conversation.

Comment: @TinyGiant So your assertion that it was on topic was something that you knew was irrelivant then, you just posted a comment to say that the question was reasonable and nothing else?  What's your basis for believing that the question was "reasonable"?  How do you know it was adequately researched, given that that's the question at hand?  And how does that relate tot he question containing a code sample demonstrating the problem (which, again, has nothing to do with being adequately researched).

Comment: Your entire comment is irrelevant but you posted it anyway. My assertion was  that based on the description provided and nothing else whatsoever, it sounds reasonable and on-topic. Based on that description alone and nothing else, I see no reason to react adversely to the question in any way as there is no evidence to suggest that such a reaction would be necessary. That is not the same as saying that any question  that could possibly fit that description must be reasonable and on-topic. You're the one going off on this tangent trying to prove who knows what. @Servy

Comment: @TinyGiant So why do you think that whether or not the question is "on topic" has anything to do with this discussion?  This is a question what it means for a question to be adequately researched, not about what is on topic.  When you say you think it's "reasonable" what do you mean?  Do you think it was adequately researched?  If so, what about that description (which has nothing at all to do with the research done) makes you think that it was well researched?  If it was about something else, then it's irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree with Servy on this. I can't think of any type of question that doesn't require research before posting! If we're talking about the question in hand, a quick Google search for ["how to get user input in c# console.read"](https://www.google.com/q=how+to+get+user+input+in+c%23+console.read) returns [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7280591/4934172) as the first result, which is an _**exact duplicate**_ to that question.

Comment: *you might not be familiar with the terms and therefore your ability to do research is not at its best.* @AhmedAbdelhameed That could be the case but it could also be that they found information that could help them but didn't understand it. Just knowing that they're new doesn't tell other users what the problem is.

Comment: @Ahmed great! You found a duplicate! Close the damn question. That has no bearing on my argument and is perfectly in line with it. Have a nice day.

Comment: @KevinB yep responding to why was this downvoted is more often than not a trap. Much the same as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313992/are-other-reviewers-opting-to-use-no-comment-to-avoid-confrontation-and-is-this)

Answer (score 21):

No.

You can do research  by asking questions, but what we mean when we say "do your research before posting" is that we expect you to have done *most* of the initial legwork in getting your question answered *before* you ask a question here.

Just asking the question here isn't enough to satisfy our research requirement.

Comment: It's not just that it "isn't enough" - it doesn't count in the least because that's not what we mean by "research effort."

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  Eh...I've asked questions here and the comments have provided valuable leads on which to go off of before.  It *helps* when one refers to research, but it isn't the end-all.

Comment: I would have phrased the last sentence as _"Asking the question here isn't necessarily enough to satisfy our research requirement, though the issue at hand may not require displays of research. It depends entirely on the question asked, and should be judged on a case by case basis"_

Comment: @TinyGiant:  I've never seen a question here asked in the "modern" era of Stack Overflow which lacked suitable research survive for very long.  Are you conflating this with code samples?

Comment: No, a straight-forward question on an untouched topic generally doesn't require much in the way of research. It's when we get into established topics where it is unclear why any of the thousand+ other questions on the topic don't answer the question being asked that we want people to show their research in order to differentiate their question from those other questions. New topics arise every day, the fact that we have established topics should not dictate the behavior for every topic. As I said, this should be judged on a case by case basis.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  Feel encouraged to post that position as a separate answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think I disagree with you. In particular, I consider experimenting with code and observing the resulting behavior a form of research. Even in an untouched topic, we expect the author to *try* to build a solution first, and they should demonstrate why some obvious approach didn't or can't work out. While this is not reading someone else's work, it is research (the gathering of information in an attempt to generate an answer to some question). Every question should have *something* of this nature, or we'd have to allow, "How do I add two numbers?" for every language.

Answer (score 15):

## Context is king

In what context are we considering the word "research"? To your employer, asking a Stack Overflow question might be research for solving the problem of getting their code shippable. To a student, it might be research for getting their assignment done. But that is not the context for us, as readers and potential answerers of a question, on Stack Overflow.

*Within the context of Stack Overflow*, research is conventionally used to mean efforts to gather information to better understand or find a solution to the problem being posited by the question. This meaning becomes blatantly obvious when you examine the [various](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373615/1394393) [contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=research) in which Stack Overflow's guidance uses the word. This is further demonstrated by reading anything about the topic on Meta, like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1394393) for example. One might argue it's a bit of shorthand, but it isn't jargon. Our usage is completely consistent with the word's general meaning; we just use it for a slightly more narrow meaning because other meanings of research are rarely (never?) relevant to our activities as users.

## This person is trying to use a linguistic trick

Rather than tackle what you actually meant or the actual problem at hand, this person is just trying to play a linguistic trick. They are trying to recast the word to mean something you obviously did not intend or imply, is not consistent with how the word is used in this context, and is not a consequence of your point; this allows them to argue against a strawman. This is just an attempt to appear clever, feel superior, and try to make you look or feel foolish. In reality, they just look rude.

I don't think you'd be unjustified if you flagged the comment, if you're inclined to. But there's much to be said for having a thick skin, as well.

Answer (score 10):

If asking a question on Stack Overflow was considered by Stack Overflow to be a show of research effort, they probably wouldn't have gone to the trouble of putting a button on every single question labeled "This question does not show any research effort".

[image]

As far as research effort is concerned, I think it's safe to assume that that button is there for us to click when we think the question does not show any<sup>1</sup>, and if the act of asking the question was intended to be interpreted as a display of research effort in and of itself, it would be nonsensical for the button to have that text associated with it.

<sub>1. Of course we can click it for other reasons as well</sub>

Comment: Exactly so. The text of the tooltip on the downvote button is clear and unambiguous, and answers the OP's question completely. I'm amazed at the number of comments this question is generating.

Comment: @skomisa It's meta, we'll happily debate any topic to death ;-)

Comment: What if the question was highly upvoted?