# When are questions asking about the details of a class, function, or other constructs on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I stumbled [over a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57545065/6296561) (image for <10k users in case the question gets deleted):

> [image]

This question was closed with this (custom) reason:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a documentation search engine.

I agree this probably could've been easily researched without asking an entire question on SO, but I highly doubt the close reason is justified. There is probably *a* close reason for it, but it mainly seems like it got closed for being a trivial question.

The real reason I'm asking this question is because there are several questions like these. For an instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3477422/6296561), which asks what a specific class is for, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3995825/6296561), which asks how to use an attribute, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/6296561), which asks what a keyword means, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39487065/6296561), which asks what a specific return statement does. (Found by searching for `[tag] what does do is:q`)

The last one is actually a fantastic example, because the accepted answer actually references the documentation, but the question isn't closed even though it could be googled and answered without Stack Overflow.

When are questions asking about what a function/class does or, for functions, returns on-topic?

<sub>This isn't an attempt to call out the close voters of the question, but I'd like to know if closing is the right action to take with these types of questions, and when that's appropriate. I've seen several new questions similar to this one, so if closing is the right thing to do, that'd be nice to know.</sub>

Comment: Related: [*Does Stack Overflow need useless questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339216/2751851)

Comment: ...when they are [not too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)?

Comment: As long as the question is clear, contains all the necessary information, I can't see a problem with such questions. The getExpansionLoc questions fails in that. It is unclear which if/then block op talks about and there is no code to clear that up. Asking about the behaviour of a function in a specific context is imho something else than asking about the meaning of a language feature.

Comment: I'd argue that 9 years ago, Android's official documentation was lacking much compared to now... Of course, fast forward to now, after the official documentation has been improved, the questions look kinda obsolete (which I think SO's goal is achieved?). I can't comment for other programming languages though.

Comment: @AndrewT. tbf, only two of the linked questions were Android. I can't say much about the status of the documentations back then, but I guess that's something that might be worth taking into account on whether the question is off-topic or not?

Comment: The other aspect about a question like this is: the person could (should!) test it themselves and then, if there's a problem with the result, ask about *that*.

Comment: "off-topic" means something entirely different in Stack Overflow-speak than elsewhere. The word "topic" refers to something specific. The general QA-knowledge base format of Stack Overflow is not a "topic". What is the topic from which the question is "off?" Imagine all the frustration that could be saved if that was replaced by words that precisely express why the question isn't good for the site. Words mean things. We need to use the right ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These kinds of questions have been always on topic.  The important thing to note is that the *scope* of what's being asked has to be reasonable, and it has to be fairly unambiguous as to what's being asked of others.

For that reason I'm going to set *aside* your first three questions - they were asked during the formative years of the site and the site was still trying to figure out what it wanted to be.

That leaves [this last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39487065/1079354), which is a reasonable and well-scoped question to ask.  The OP was trying to establish what this particular syntax meant - it *reads* like it'd be something which is arcane or ill-explained in the spec.  Something that provides clarification for this is indeed valuable.

Where the question you've linked falls flat is that the context is absent.  That's about it.

> I need to know what does `clang::SourceManager::getExpansionLoc` give?
>
> For example, in the then section of if statement.

Without knowing anything about C++ or Clang, I can't piece together the exact `if` statement they're using, nor do I know what context they're executing it under that's giving them the ambiguity.

It *should* be closed as "unclear what you're asking".  The close voter here did the right thing with the wrong reason, since now the OP has to go back and provide that context.

I just regret the fact that this message wasn't delivered to them in time...

Comment: "wasn't delivered to them in time..." In time for what? They can always edit their own question, right? And that will put it in the reopen queue, since no one else has edited it in the meantime? It's only been a few hours... let's not bemoan the fate of this question for all time when it is still in its youth.

Comment: @HereticMonkey:  There are...shall we say, "differing perceptions" of the lifecycle of a question.  Some people hold that the bias of moderation is fluid and can be changed. Others hold that the bias of moderation is calcified the instant that there's some kind of negatively-interpreted moderation on their content.  It's a mix of both in some cases; some people believe that moderation is bad/unfriendly/unwelcoming/un-***whatever***, and they rail against it.  I'm making an observation that there are some people who will take this experience to heart and hold that bias against us forever.

Comment: So, "in time" to save the first impression? Fair enough. I guess I figured when they added the "on hold" status, that was meant to signal that it was temporary; that a user could still edit the question into shape and get it reopened.