# Should users asking questions about a specific class in a programming language include a tag for that class?

Tags: discussion, tags

I’ve noticed a common pattern in Swift questions. They ask a problem about a class, tag Swift, and then the class. Should users tag the class name or leave it out?

One reason not to is the lack of attention these tags get. Very few, if any, people are experts with a particular class and actively seek out questions in that class by searching by tag.

However, I usually leave the tags when editing. I do this out of respect for the author and any potential answerers.

What should I do when editing these questions? Should I leave the tags or remove them? And for the question askers, should they be used in the first place?

I’ve seen [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388635/when-are-questions-asking-about-the-details-of-a-class-function-or-other-const) and it seems to be more focused questions on details about the class itself, not questions relating to the class that use class tags.

Comment: If you feel that particular tags are not useful you can create burnination request (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)... otherwise I'd leave them alone - don't add but don't remove either (as long as tags are appropriate for the question).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "class tags" with an example of a tag and/or an example question?

Comment: It is the one thing we never have to teach new users, they instinctively know that a *language* tag like [swift] isn't enough to ask for help with a user interface problem.  So they add more tags, don't remove them.

Comment: @Hans I _guess_ they mean `Label` as a tag instead of `WinForms`, for example. Edit: oh, only 12.5K questions in the [UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uicollectionview) tag...

Comment: Or 62K in [UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview). Looks like they're very relevant indeed.

Comment: What determines if a class is notable enough to get its own tag? The number of classes in .NET is on the order of 10,000.