"which library...?" Should I assume "library" is external library by default?
According to the answer of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312955/22045979, as I understand, asking standard library is different from asking external library, which asking standard library is not tool recommendation, but asking external library is.
Then I came across 2 questions:
Which library in C language can I use for toupper and tolower?
How can I use the pow() function?
These two are currently closed as tool recommendations. However, at this time, the question is uses the term "which library" instead of "which external library", and there are internal libraries (standard library in the language) that can do the job that the question asks for.
Is the policy about difference between asking standard library and external library changed? For similar cases in the future, if the question uses the term "which library" only, should I assume it is about an external library even if the job can be done by internal library?

Internal/external, the question is still off-topic if it's a library recommendation.

Why do you feel that the library being internal/external makes a difference? The VTC/Flag reason is "Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources" ; it doesn't state internal/external. Likewise the closure notice states "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources. You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations."; no mention of internal/external

The first question would have been better asked as "How do I convert a character to uppercase / lowecase?" One could downvote it for lack of research effort but it would be on-topic (potentially duplicate). The second one... at least the closure reason there isn't suitable (There are suitable duplicates that could be used instead).

Instead of the referenced answer, another answer to the same meta question gives better guidiance for avoiding "recommendation" trap. That answer explicitly doesn't distinguish "internal" and "external" libraries.

That other answer also shows that the second question (about pow) is not a recommendation question, it is literally phrased as "how can I use a pow function in C".

@AbdulAzizBarkat one could downvote for lack of research, but one shouldn't. That bit of the description is simply the typical... undercooked? Stack Overflow writing style. One should downvote if the question is unclear or not useful... typically caused by a lack of research, but not guaranteed. Suggestive writing is such a bad idea.

In the first question you linked, they meant 'Which header file' probably.

Realistically, most people who ask for a library are only assuming they need a third-party library. And if the standard library does the job, they should be told as much. Just convert the question to "how do I... ?". Problems that can be fixed by editing, without the OP's input, should be; don't waste time on close/reopen for that.

You're making a false dichotomy here– we don't close questions under the "Seeking Recommendations" reason because they use an external vs. internal library.
That close reason exists because questions where the core concern is picking a library rather than accomplishing a task are almost always too subjective for Stack Overflow, for the reasons outlined in the wiki post covering this close reason.

See also: What's the difference between "How can I do X?" and "What library does X?"

Note that neither of the two questions in the OP have picking a library as the core concern, they are about performing math tasks (rounding up and down and taking the power). The only issue is that they are phrased such that close voters might think that the question is about comparing or suggesting libraries.

@Marijn That's absolutely fair, and I have a fair amount of frustration with the prevalence of that tendency to close first rather than salvage; I also wouldn't really fault anyone for closing that second question during its first revision, which ended with "I do not find any library that have power function? Please introduce me a library have this function".
